# Flex box container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create one flex container, which has 3 child items. However, I want two of the child items to be columns, and the third one to be a row which runs below of the the columns (like a footer). Is it possible?

Comment: check this flexbox guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best achieved by using two divs, one flex-box, and one that isn't: see below:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#a {
background-color: lightgreen;
}
#b {
background-color: lightgray;
}
#c {
background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="a">This is a</div>
  <div id="b">This is b</div>
</div>
<div id="c">This is c</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like [THIS](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kpw149yq/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.row {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-container">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```